# Trigger XDebug session remotely in NetBeans

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, xdebug

In Eclipse I could use the Easy XDebug tool for Firefox to start a debugging session by clicking the debug icon and refreshing the page.  Eclipse would then launch its debugger.

This doesn't seem to work in NetBeans, the debugger doesn't start.  You can start the debugger in NetBeans first, then start debugging in FireFox, but if you're not already in debug mode in NetBeans then the easy XDebug plugin has no effect.

Is it possible for debugging to be triggered externally in NetBeans?  If so, how do I set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be no way to start debugger remotelly. However you have to start debugging session only once per browser launch, and then you can enable/disable with browser icon.

Work around to prevent browser from launching is to set it to `ls` or some other tiny process which start and vanish instantly.